# LaTeX weird alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm new with stackexchange and I'm not sure if I post this question the right way, please let me know if I need to provide additional information.

I can't identify the source of this alignment problem I'm having. Between to adjacent pages, the document alignment changes, here is a picture of how it looks like after compiling

[image]

I include these packages in my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,two side,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{CJK}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `twoside` option (*rectius* for `two side`) is responsible for this.

Comment: The purpose of the offset is to allow room for stapling of (two-sided) pages.

Comment: In Mac Preview select `View/Two Pages` and it should be clear that the purpose of this extra space in between two pages is for the binding when printing a large document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different position on the sheet of paper of the type block for even and odd pages is an effect of the `twoside` option. You have it in the options to the document class (albeit in the improper `two side` form).

The option sets up the output so that, roughly speaking, the three strips of white space (left, center and right) are approximately equal, so the two page spread appears uniformly when the document is printed and looked at from a distance.

Just remove the option and the type block will be centered on the paper.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to bind your document and want the pages to be the same, set the odd and even side margins using

```
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0in}
\setlength\evensidemargin{0in}
```

Place those two lines of code after the page width and page height are set.